# Deleting a particular node using the e4x syntax

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex4

I have this XML structure:

```
<numb>
  <variable>
   <name>john</name>
   <age>12</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
   <name>janet</name>
   <age>10</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
   <name>johanna</name>
   <age>22</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
  <name>harry</name>
  <age>24</age>
 </variable>
</numb>
```

If I try to delete the variable with name *johanna* I do this:

```
  delete numb.variable.(name=="johanna);
```

but then, I get this error:

```
 "Error #1119: Delete operator is not supported with operand of type XMLList"
```

suggesting the numb.variable.(name=="johanna") is an XMLList ..but then I tried this:

```
delete XML(numb.variable.(numb=="johanna");
```

but that didn't delete anything..

Anyone knows how I could delete a certain variable in the numb XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the child nodes that have a different **name** from *johanna* and set those as the children nodes, using the [setChildren()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#setChildren%28%29) method.

e.g.

```
var xml:XML = <numb>
  <variable>
   <name>john</name>
   <age>12</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
   <name>janet</name>
   <age>10</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
   <name>johanna</name>
   <age>22</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
  <name>harry</name>
  <age>24</age>
 </variable>
</numb>

xml.setChildren(xml.variable.(name != 'johanna'));
trace(xml);
/*
Outputs:
<numb>
  <variable>
    <name>john</name>
    <age>12</age>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <name>janet</name>
    <age>10</age>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <name>harry</name>
    <age>24</age>
  </variable>
</numb>
*/
```

Another option is to loop through each node that satisfies the condition and delete the corresponding node through array access notation using the [childIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#childIndex%28%29) method:

short version:

```
for each (var match:XML in xml.variable.(name == 'johanna')) delete xml.variable[match.childIndex()];
```

longer version:

```
var xml:XML = <numb>
  <variable>
   <name>john</name>
   <age>12</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
   <name>janet</name>
   <age>10</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
   <name>johanna</name>
   <age>22</age>
 </variable>
 <variable>
  <name>harry</name>
  <age>24</age>
 </variable>
</numb>;

var matches:XMLList = xml.variable.(name == 'johanna');
for each (var match:XML in matches) delete xml.variable[match.childIndex()];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
numb.variable.(name=="johanna")
```

return an xmllist of one xml element, so to delete it you have to use this syntax

```
delete numb.variable.(name=="johanna)[0] as XML;
```